# glue job for redshift connection: "Unable to find suitable security group"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm trying to set up a AWS Glue job and make a connection to Redshift.

I'm getting error when I set the connection type to Redshift:

> "Unable to find a suitable security group. Change connection type to
>   JDBC and retry adding your connection."

Following what was said [here in these forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261983), I added permissions to my IAM account for role `AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault`:

[image]

I then set up the job with the matching IAM role `AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault`:

[image]

I need to store the Glue data in Redshift DB, so I chose JDBC then added a connection:

[image]

As soon as I choose `Redshift`, it complains that it cannot find a suitable security group. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 32):

I found the same issue when trying to connect Glue with Amazon RDS (MySQL) and solved it following the AWS Glue guidelines -> [Setting Up a VPC to Connect to JDBC Data Stores](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html).

In a nutshell you should check that the security group associated to your RedShift cluster allows self-referencing traffic.

1. Go to RedShift console and choose *Clusters*
2. Look at the *Cluster Properties* section for the ID of the security group associated to the cluster (e.g. sg-957be3ef).
3. Click at the security group name to jump to the EC2 console -> Security groups section. Choose the group and modify the Inbound and Outbound rules adding self-referencing rule to allow AWS Glue components to communicate.

   - Inbound rules: chose Type=*All TCP*, leave the default values and type the security group in the *Source* field (i.e. sg-957be3ef for this example).
   - Outbound rules: same as Inbound rules.

Hope that works!

Comment: After setting up self-referencing rule, I had an issue on SSH to my endpoint, it ends up the port open to 22 from 0.0.0.0/0 is needed.

Comment: Same exact issue, and this solution did the trick! Thank you sir 

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing for for a postgres database but when trying to add the security group in the source field from inbound rules I get this message: `You may not specify a referenced group id for an existing IPv4 CIDR rule.` I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a:

1)`AWSGlueServiceRole` role and attach `s3FullAccess,GlueServiceRole` and `RedshiftFullAccess` policy.

2)Check you have vpc Endpoint, If not create a VPC endpoint and make sure subnets are added to route table.
3)Create self referencing security group.

Now connect using JDBC connection,

```
jdbc:type://xxxx:port/databasename
```

type is `redshift/postgresql/etc`...
`xxxx: server name` where the database hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Use JDBC connection instead to connect to your Redshift. Just ensure the corresponding VPC has an end-point defined.